# Any method to extract colors of background and foreground of a webpage by web scraping?

Tags: html, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to extract the colors of the background and foreground of a given webpage . Are there any web scraping techniques related to it? I want to calculate the color contrast ratio of the web page.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is a bit too broad for this forum. However, I think a good starting point taking would be to take a look a browser emulation like: `playwright` (available in many languages). You can use it to start browser -> connect to url -> get a screenshot of the page -> save the screenshot and analyze contrast ratio with some image processor like `pillow` for Python. A bit more difficult approach would be to scrape html page -> extract css file -> scrape css file -> analyze css styles for contrast details. Come back once you have something :)

Comment: thx i didn't think about an approach like that . I will definitely try it and reach back to you later!